# Use opencv in mex function

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, opencv, mex

I wanted to use opencv library in a mex function but it just kept telling me that opencv functions had not been declared. So I searched a bit and found out I should link them somehow but I couldn't figure out how.

Can anybody help me with that?

I'm using opencv2.4.2 and matlab 2012 on a 64-bit ubuntu11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i could't exactly solve the problem but I found [this project](http://www.cs.stonybrook.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/index.html) which had done it and I just edited its functions and it worked fine.